# с XML файла в таблицу

Tags: php, xml

> Моя задача, получив XML файл преобразовать в таблицы (в данном случае в три таблицы). Как отобразить все таблицы? В данный момент удалось отобразить только одну.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
    <book> 
        <title>Heart of a Dog</title>
        <author>Mikhail Bulgakov</author>
        <released>1925</released>
        <country>Russia</country>
        <price>389</price>
        <currency>EUR</currency>
        <discount>0</discount>
        <img>/img/001.jpg</img>
    </book>
    <book> 
        <title>Postmortem</title>
        <author>Patricia Cornwell</author>
        <released>1990</released>
        <country>USA</country>
        <price>320</price>
        <currency>EUR</currency>
        <discount>80</discount>
        <img>/img/002.jpg</img>
    </book>
    <book> 
        <title>The Sign of the Four</title>
        <author>Arthur Conan Doyle</author>
        <released>1890</released>
        <country>United Kingdom</country>
        <price>300</price>
        <currency>EUR</currency>
        <discount>50</discount>
        <img>/img/003.jpg</img>
    </book>
</books>
```

```php
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('books.xml');

foreach ($xml as $x) {
   $title = $x->title;
   $author = $x->author;
   $country = $x->country;
   $released = $x->released;
   $price = $x->price;
   $currency = $x->currency;
   $discount = $x->discount;
   $image = $x->image;
}
?>
```

```html
<html>

   <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="250px" >
   <tr>
   <td colspan="2" <td style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#333;">
                 <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
   </td> 
   </tr> <tr>
   <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#333;">
                 <?php echo $title . ", " . $author; ?> 
   </td> 
   </tr><tr>
   <td style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#333;">
                 <?php echo "Country: " .$country; ?>
   </td> 
   <td style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#333;">
                 <?php echo "Price: ".$price." ".$currency; ?>
   </td> 
   </tr><tr>
   <td style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#333;">
                <?php echo "Publication date: ".$released; ?> 
   </td>
   <td style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#333;">
                <?php echo "Discount: ".$discount." ".$currency; ?>
   </td>
   </tr>
   </table>

</html>
```

Comment: попробуйте повнятнее сформулировать вопрос. что за Table? это database table, html table, или еще какой нибудь? Какие все таблицы? тут речь идет про `books` какие-то

Comment: Мая задача, получив XML файл преобразовать в таблицы (в данном случае в три таблицы) помогите разобраться.

Comment: Ответ тут: [XML to table format. I get only one table. I need to display two tables, how to do it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250441/xml-to-table-format-i-get-only-one-table-i-need-to-display-two-tables-how-to)

Answer (score 1):

Вы сначала проходите цикл foreach, а потом 1 раз рисуете таблицу, поэтому 1 строчка и получается. Вам нужно:

1) открыть таблицу, (тег `<table>`)

2) Пройтись циклом foreach по объекту $xml: в каждой итерации прорисовать строчку (тег `<tr>`)

3)После завершения всех итераций закрыть таблицу (`</table>`).

Comment: Благодарю за оперативность ответ hett!,  Если честно, я ничего не понял. И дело не Вас "не моя сфера компетенции". Если Вас не затруднит, выложите готовый код, пожалуйста.

Comment: php под рукой нет. Смотрите допустим у вас 5 записей в xml. Вы xml конвертируете в обобьет $xml, приходитесь по нему 5 раз, в каждой итерации ничего не делаете, а потом 1 раз рисуете таблицу используя переменные которые были заполнены в последней итерации , а вам нужно в каждой итерации рисовать 1 строчку для таблицы.

Comment: **php под рукой нет…**  -Hiff! буду терпеливо ждать.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, зачем Вам именно 3 таблицы, но делается все аналогично Вашему способу.. В любом случае таблицы Вам придется рисовать в php.

Простейший пример:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('book.xml');
$i=1;

foreach ($xml as $x) {

    echo('<p> Таблица №'.$i++.'</p>');  
    echo"<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$x->title}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$x->author}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$x->country}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$x->price}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$x->currency}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$x->discount}</td>";
    echo "<td><img src={$x->img}></td>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$books = simplexml_load_file('books.xml');
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .table {
            width: 250px;

            border-collapse: separate;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            border-spacing: 0;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        .table td {
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            color: #333;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php foreach ($books as $book): ?>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <img src="<?php echo $book->img; ?>" alt="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <?php echo $book->title . ', ' . $book->author; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Country: <?php echo $book->country; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Price: <?php echo $book->price . ' ' . $book->currency; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Publication date: <?php echo $book->released; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Discount: <?php echo $book->discount . ' ' . $book->currency; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</body>
</html>
```